# JavaScript onClick with Inputfield Not Working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm a JavaScript beginner. I'm trying to make a text show up on clicking a button, but it's not working. I'm trying to create a guessing game where the user inputs a number into the field to guess a random number created by JavaScript.I'd appreciate your help!

```
<div class="wrap" >
 Project: Guessing Game

 <input type="text" name="inputField" value="" id="inputField">
 <button id="guess">Guess!</button>
 <br>
 <p id="output"></p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var $ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
};

// var myNumber = Math.random();

// var randomIntegerRange = function(min,max){
//  return Math.round(((Math.random()*(max-min))+min));
// };

// randomIntegerRange(1,4);

var myButton = $("#guess");

var myInput = $("#inputField");

var myOutput = $("#output");


myButton.onClick = function () {
myOutput.innerHTML += "Your number is bigger than the random number";
};

</script>
```

Comment: Where are you registering an event listener?

Comment: Have a look here for the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9thB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In contrast to html attributes the property names are case sensitive in JavaScript. Therefore you have to use `myButton.onclick` instead.

```
<button oNcLiCk="alert('Hallo')">
```

Another and probably cleaner way are event listeners.

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    myOutput.innerHTML += "Your number is bigger than the random number";
});
```